# Laravel - Request safe method does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-request

I generated my StorePostRequest using artisan make command.
I defined rules on the rules method doing this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
        'slug' => ['required', Rule::unique('posts', 'slug')],
        'thumbnail' =>'required|image',
        'excerpt' => 'required|min:3',
        'body' => 'required|min:3',
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id'
    ];
}
```

However, in my PostController, I'm not able to get validated inputs except `thumbnail` using the `safe()->except('thumbnail')` like explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests)

I'm getting the error

```
BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Requests\StorePostRequest::safe does not exist.
```

Comment: `$validated = $request->safe()->except(['thumbnail'])`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, ``$request->safe()->except(['thumbnail'])`` doesn't work either

Comment: You can use `only()` to get some specified inputs 
`$validated = $request->only(['// all keys you need']);

Comment: thanks for your help, ``$request->except('thumbnail')`` worked.

Comment: @Nel Word of warning if you use the $request->except() you are getting all the requests fields even those that did not pass the validation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `except()` method directly on `$request` worked. Thanks to @JEJ for his help.

```
$request->except('thumbnail');
```

Comment: This is not safe though. The resulting collection may include key/values that are not present in the rules list as they will pass unfiltered.

Answer (score 4):

Check your laravel/framework version by running

`php artisan --version`

The safe method found on the FormRequest class [was only added in version](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v8.55.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php) `8.55.0`.

Just good to keep in mind that just because you're on **a** version 8 of laravel framework, that doesn't mean you'll have all methods and properties found in the laravel 8.x docs. That is unless you're on the current latest version 8 of course.